# How to get the "For the Audience" achievement?

Tags: might-and-magic-heroes-6

Is there a way to ght the `For the Audience` achievement in Might & Magic Heroes VI?

The achievement says `Kill Michael with at least 4 minions still alive.`, but every time he takes damage it is redirected to his minions. Only when all the minions are dead, you can kill Michael. Is this a bug or it is possible to prevent this damage redirecting ability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this thread](http://forums.ubi.com/showthread.php/363997-Hard-to-get-or-unclear-achievements-%28now-with-100-more-guide-and-spoilers%29) on the Ubiforums:

> So to come back to how I manage to do For the Audience, the main point
>   is indeed to manage to petrify 4 gardians at a time. To do so here are
>   the prerequisites :
>
> - A magical tear heroe with full Earth branch boosted (including earth elemental, petrification and 3xEarth power)
> - If possible avoid taking counter-attack talents (not to kill too much gardians with retaliations)
> - Being a Sanctuary hero will help (Tsunami incapacitate the gardians for 2 turns and Race ability gives an interesting ponctual damage
>     boost)
> - Buy as much scroll of Earth Elementals as you can
> - Staff of Asha lvl 5 is mandatory
> - Vast archer/casters army but not too vast not to kill gardians upon retaliation on Michael (archers have most of the time a lesser
>     retaliation power). Avoid at all cost infinite retaliations units
>     (griffins, hell hounds etc.)   When you have all this, here is
>     approximately the sequence you need to perform :
> - First round: Petrification (with Staff of Asha lvl 5, it should last at least 9 turns), spread your units all over the map.
> - Second round: Invoke earth elemental in a corner of the map, gards every other unit
> - Third round: Tsunami, this will stun all gardians and get rid of retaliation kills
> - Fourth round: reinforce your highest attack unit stack. Gard all units.
> - Fifth round: cast petrification once again (it should last 4 turns), make all units wait, including your earth elems. When the
>     earth elem turn comes again, make it petrify a gardian and go to next
>     turn.
> - Sixth round: this is it ! You should be first in the order, so cast a new earth elem spell and anything that could help your damage so far
>     (Sanctuary racial ability for example). With these new elems, petrify
>     the fourth gardian stack and FULL ATTACK. The goal is to take over
>     Michael before any of the gardian de-petrify, which is a very short
>     lapse of time. If this happens, STOP ALL damage and wait for being
>     able to cast a spell again. When possible, cast a new earth elemental
>     using a scroll (no cooldown) and re-petrify the gardian.   There is a
>     big part of technique (/luck/improvisation) to make the plan work but
>     it is feasible. You just have to insist. Maybe there is a simpler way
>     but I did not find it (yet).